# Link Radiobox button to Input

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I have 2 radio button, each valued Yes and No respectively and 1 textbox.. If I checked on No button, the input textbox will open. If checked on Yes, textbox will disabled.

This code is working fine but I want to delete content that input to the textbox if the user checked Yes

```js
function ismcstopu() {
  var chkNo = document.getElementById("radio2_ismcstop");
  var mcnostopreason = document.getElementById("mcnostopreason");
  mcnostopreason.disabled = chkNo.checked ? false : true;
  if (!mcnostopreason.disabled) {
    mcnostopreason.focus();
  } else {
    mcnostopreason.val('');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1_ismcstop" name="ismcstop" onclick="ismcstopu()" value="Yes">Yes
<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2_ismcstop" name="ismcstop" onclick="ismcstopu()" value="No">No
<label for="mcnostopreason">If No, Reason:</label>
<input class="inputstyle-100" type="text" id="mcnostopreason" name="mcnostopreason" value="" disabled>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.val is a jQuery construct but you are using DOM

Here is a better version using eventListener

Change the `document.getElementById("container")` to whatever container you have (your form for example)

Note: It is often better to test true than to test false
I also added labels to the radios so we can click the yes or no too

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.name === "ismcstop") {
    const mcnostopreason = document.getElementById("mcnostopreason");
    mcnostopreason.disabled = tgt.value === "Yes";
    if (mcnostopreason.disabled) {
      mcnostopreason.value = '';
    } else {
      mcnostopreason.focus();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <label><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1_ismcstop" name="ismcstop" value="Yes">Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2_ismcstop" name="ismcstop" value="No">No</label>
  <label for="mcnostopreason">If No, Reason:
    <input class="inputstyle-100" type="text" id="mcnostopreason" name="mcnostopreason" value="" disabled>
  </label>
</div>
```

jQuery version

```js
$("[name=ismcstop]").on("click", function() {
  if (this.name === "ismcstop") {
    const $mcnostopreason = $("#mcnostopreason");
    $mcnostopreason.prop("disabled", this.value === "Yes");
    if ($mcnostopreason.is(":disabled")) {
      $mcnostopreason.val("");
    } else {
      $mcnostopreason.focus();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1_ismcstop" name="ismcstop" value="Yes">Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2_ismcstop" name="ismcstop" value="No">No</label>
<label for="mcnostopreason">If No, Reason:
  <input class="inputstyle-100" type="text" id="mcnostopreason" name="mcnostopreason" value="" disabled>
</label>
```

Comment: Yes.. The one that I accept is come first.. A few minutes after that this solution come out.. But both solution is great.. Thank You guys

Answer (score 1):

`mcnostopreason` is not a jQuery object. therefore you could do: `var mcnostopreason = $("#mcnostopreason");`

Or you could just change `mcnostopreason.val('')` to `mcnostopreason.value = ''` ( this will mean you don't need to change anything else)

Comment: BTW .val() is a jQuery method, which is why the error is thrown

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I'm new in web development and always confused between JQuery and Javascript.

Comment: Same thing happens to me! I've basically memorized the error! If you like my answer, please mark it as answered

Comment: If they change to `$("#mcnostopreason");` they also need to change .disabled to .prop("disabled",....) or .is(".disabled") like I did in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66434632/295783)